# Upgrading an old laravel application to laravel 8 raised this jessenger/date errors

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-upgrade

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - barryvdh/laravel-debugbar is locked to version v2.3.2 and an update of this package was not requested.
s with another require.
  Problem 2
    - barryvdh/laravel-dompdf is locked to version v0.8.2 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - barryvdh/laravel-dompdf v0.8.2 requires illuminate/support 5.1.x|5.2.x|5.3.x|5.4.x|5.5.x|5.6.x -> found illuminate/support[v5.1.1, ..., v5.6.39] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
  Problem 3
    - barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper is locked to version v2.3.2 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper v2.3.2 requires illuminate/console ^5.0,<5.5 -> found illuminate/console[v5.0.0, ..., v5.4.36] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
  Problem 4
    - kyslik/column-sortable is locked to version 5.4.11 and an update of this package was not requested.
ire.
    - laravelcollective/html is locked to version v5.4.9 and an update of this package was not requested.
  Problem 6
    - nwidart/laravel-menus is locked to version 0.5.0 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - nwidart/laravel-menus 0.5.0 requires illuminate/config 5.4.* -> found illuminate/config[v5.4.0, ..., v5.4.36] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
  Problem 7
    - nwidart/laravel-modules is locked to version 1.27.2 and an update of this package was not requested.
re (5.8.0).
  Problem 8
    - sofa/eloquence is locked to version 5.4.1 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - sofa/eloquence 5.4.1 requires illuminate/database 5.4.* -> found illuminate/database[v5.4.0, ..., v5.4.36] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
```

has raised this errors it tried to install each package seperatly but still didnt work.
can anyone help me through this.

Comment: Please add more details about your problem.

Comment: I tried to update a laravel 5.4 application by updating it using composer update command

Comment: You need to check each package you are using that requires laravel and check which version of Laravel the version of the package you are using requires. For example laravelcollective/html supports laravel 8 starting version 6 but you are using version 5. The composer messages should give you an idea of which packages don't work with your new laravel version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try reinstalling the packages. remove all and install them again